# Getting Text Orientation on Tesseract - Python API

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm using the Tesseract Python Wrapper to obtain the orientation of a text image. When I use the Tesseract-OCR (not the API), setting the mode to -psm 0 works, but I don't know how to extract that information while using the wrapper. 
I've seen the documentation, and I tried to use the method AnalyseLayout, but I don't seem to find the correct way to do it. Any ideas??

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, were you able to this and how ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following is how to do it in Java. I guess it should be similar for Python.

```
    IntBuffer orientation = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    IntBuffer direction = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    IntBuffer order = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    FloatBuffer deskew_angle = FloatBuffer.allocate(1);
    int success = api.TessBaseAPIRecognize(handle, null);
    if (success == 0) {
        TessAPI.TessPageIterator pi = api.TessBaseAPIAnalyseLayout(handle);
        api.TessPageIteratorOrientation(pi, orientation, direction, order, deskew_angle);
    }
```

Comment: I tried to do it in Python but I can't define well the parameters of the method Orientation. Thanks anyway!